# Missing line content when reading file with bash

Tags: bash

I'm trying to read this file (env.cfg)

```
AXXL_EXCHANGE="/home/company/RECETTE/data"
HOME_LOG="/home/company/RECETTE/logs"
PXXWS_ALERT=user@company.com
PXXWS_DAV=https://URL/ascl/webdav
PXXWS_URL=https://URL/ascl/services
PXXWS_PEM=/home/folder/RECETTE/conf
PXXWS_XSLT=/home/folder/RECETTE/conf
PXXWS_PWD=
PXXWS_CURL="-m 3600 -k" # max-time 3600 (tests)
TMP_DIR=/tmp
```

with the following bash script (RES.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
# read $FILE using the file descriptors
exec 3<&0
exec 0<$FILE
while read line
do
# use $line variable to process line
echo $line
done
exec 0<&3
```

here's what the script is echoing (on console)

```
AXXL_EXCHANGE="/home/company/RECETTE/data"
HOME_LOG="/home/company/RECETTE/logs"
PXXWS_ALERT=user@company.com
PXXWS_DAV=https://URL/ascl/webdav
PXXWS_URL=https://URL/ascl/services
PXXWS_PEM=/home/folder/RECETTE/conf
PXXWS_XSLT=/home/folder/RECETTE/conf
PXXWS_PWD=
PXXWS_CURL=
TMP_DIR=/tmp
```

**the last line (PASWS_CURL) right side is missing**

**environment : debian wheezy** 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use quotes to display it:

```
echo "$line"
```

Also why make it complicated to read file. Use simple while loop like this to read line by line :

```
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"
done < "$1"
```

**UPDATE:** It could be due to the presence of `\r` character in your file. Can you show output of `cat -vte file` and see the output.

Comment: The quotes doesn't seem to be necessary (but they are a good idea anyway). Try this: `x="foo # bar" ; echo $x`

Comment: @Abderrazakk: Did you try my suggested while loop code to read the file.

Comment: yes @anubhava I tried It seems the white spaces because whenI remove'em the last line appears correctly

Comment: It could be presence of `\r` character in your file. Can you show output of `cat -vte file` and show me the output.

Comment: yup got it thanks 1, please edit your response to be able to accept it

Answer (score 1):

I copied your input file and script, and didn't get that error.

If you trust the input, you can just `source $FILE`.

Otherwise, this seems simpler than juggling file descriptors:

```
cat $FILE | while read line; do echo "$line"; done
```